# Ionic2 undefined and null values when using ViewChild

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

Here's the code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'elastic-textarea',
  template:
  `
  <ion-textarea #textarea
    placeholder='{{placeholder}}'
    [(ngModel)]="content"
    (ngModelChange)='onChange($event)'></ion-textarea>
  `
})
export class ElasticTextarea {
  @ViewChild('textarea') ionTxtArea: ElementRef;

  etc...

  txtArea: any;

  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.txtArea = this.ionTxtArea.nativeElement; <- This is null
    this.txtArea.style.height = this.lineHeight + "px"; <- Crashes here
  }
```

Seems i'm doing everything correctly. However, for some reason I am unable to get a reference for that textarea element in order to do some DOM manipulation...
What's happenin?

Comment: how about `this.ionTxtArea._elementRef.nativeElement.children[0];`?

Comment: devqon, how did that work??

Answer (score 0):

devqon comment is right. But if you if you want to do like that you should change your `ViewChild` to avoid typescript error:

```
@ViewChild('textarea') ionTxtArea: any;
 ngAfterViewInit(){
    //Just log your ionTtxtArea here to see what is it:
    console.log(this.ionTxtArea);
    this.txtArea = this.ionTxtArea._elementRef.nativeElement.children[0];
    this.txtArea.style.height = this.lineHeight + "px"; 
 }
```